# How to edit quick search view dynamics crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a quick search view which looks like this:

```
-----------

customerName
-----------
```

when I change the order of the columns in my quick find view I got:

```
customerName
----------------

----------------
```

Why do I have this =>  '--------' and not the data from the columns that I choosen in my view ? where do I fix it ? is there a connection to permissions?

Comment: Share screenshot. Global search or quick find? That 2nd & 3rd columns may not have values, so empty string is showing like that. Or do you have any field level security? Is this for sys.admin too?

Comment: @ArunVinoth there are values in the fields and I am the system manager...

Comment: Seems like System manager is a custom role or renamed role, check for field security profiles.. also are you seeing those field values in form?

Comment: @ArunVinoth yes I see them in form but not in quick find...

Comment: That doesn’t sound right. Either you are looking at different fields or incorrect views, are you seeing this in a reflow form/activity card in UCI app? Screenshot makes it clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not a llowed to upload in screenshots in my workplace :(  there is no security fields and when I open the form I can see the values in the fields.

Comment: Are you talking about this search & view - Can you confirm? https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/xrm/archive/2017/08/12/how-to-set-up-global-search-in-microsoft-dynamics-365

Comment: @ArunVinoth nothing helped I deleted all the raws and added them again... and it returns work and show the values.

Comment: How many records did you delete? that could affect the visualization

Answer (score 0):

To change the field shown in the results of the quick find you can edit the quick find view of the entity

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps - M.Acosta.D